# Python, проверка аргументов метода

Tags: python, python-3.x

Получаю ошибку:

```
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Код:

```
def test(file):
  if not file:
    raise IoError
```

Вызываем, как:

```
import cv2
file = cv2.imread("1.png")
test(file)
```

Причина ясна, `imread` вернет массив `numpy`.

Но как сделать проверку в методе, что в переменной что-то есть.
Желательно, сохранить возможность вызывать метод так:

```
test("string")
```

Желательно, так-как в реальных условиях код выглядит так:

```
def method(type="camera", file):
  if type !="camera" and not file:
    raise IoError
```

То есть, вот такую проверку нужно провернуть.

Comment: imread вернет массив numpy. Проверьте длину, если больше 0, значит, что-то есть.

Comment: Ок, а как тогда будет в случае, если вместо массива придет String, или Boolean

Comment: @Lasna1 Проверьте тип при помощи функции [isinstance()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance).

Comment: со строкой то же самое, а если у вас в эту функцию может прийти тру/фалс, то, наверное, у вас в коде что-то не совсем правильно

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можете сделать проверку в зависимости от типа входной переменной.

```
import numpy as np

def test(value):
    if isinstance(value, np.ndarray):
        if not value.size:
            raise IoError
    elif not value:
        raise IoError
```